# getting values of multiple selectboxes via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, drop-down-menu

I want to fill an array in javascript that takes all the values out of different selectboxes with the same name

so for example if i have a html like this:

```
<select name="selectbox[]">
<option value="value1">text1</option>
<option value="value2">text2</option>
</select>

<select name="selectbox[]">
<option value="value1">text1</option>
<option value="value2">text2</option>
</select>
```

I have to get the selected values of both selectboxes and put it in an array.

what i did:

```
 $("input[name=selectbox\\[\\]]").map(function(){return $(this).val();});
```

does not work.

A similar example wich **does** work for textboxes:

```
$("input[name=textbox\\[\\]]").map(function(){return this.value;});
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps because its a `select` and not an `input` ??

```
var $select = $("<select multiple='multiple' />");
for (var x=0; x<3; x++) {
  $select.append("<option value='"+x+"' selected='selected'>"+x+"</option>");
}
console.log($select.val());
//  ["0", "1", "2"]
console.log($select.map(function() { return $(this).val() }));
//  jQuery("0", "1", "2")

// create a second select:
$select = $select.clone(true).andSelf();
console.log($select.map(function() { return $(this).val() }));
//  jQuery("0", "1", "2", "0", "1", "2")
```

Comment: oops, overlooked that one haha :D